# Linux size command, why are bss and data sections not zero?

Tags: memory, c, c++, elf

I came across the size command which gives the section size of the ELF file. While playing around with it, I created an output file for the simplest C++ program :

```
int main(){return 0;}
```

Clearly, I have not defined any initialized or uninitialized, data then why are my BSS and DATA sections of the size 512 and 8 bytes?

I thought it might be because of `int main()`, I tried creating object file for the following C program :

```
void main(){}
```

I still don't get 0 for BSS and DATA sections.

Is it because a certain minimum sized memory is allocated to those section?

EDIT- I thought it might be because of linked libraries but my object is dynamically linked so probably it shouldn't be the issue

Comment: There is a static library for the C runtime which is linked by the compiler, and which includes the *real* entry point which calls main(). You should see the real entry point function e.g. if you run `objdump --disassemble`.  `objdump -f` will show information including the "start address".

Comment: I see a few libraries linked to my object when i run objdump on it, the ouput of `file a.out` said it's dynamically linked ELF so i assumed there are no statically linked libraries, guess i was wrong.

Comment: Related: [A Whirlwind Tutorial on Creating Really Teensy ELF Executables for Linux](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html)

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419697/why-are-true-and-false-so-large/419704#419704 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418354/understanding-what-a-linux-binary-is-doing/418357#418357

Comment: Compile it with -g and run `nm` on it - you will see all the symbols in the elf file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In fact, if you are compiling with the libc attached to the binary, there are functions that are added before (and after) the `main()` function. They are here mostly to load dynamic libraries (even if you do not need it in your case) and unload it properly once `main()` end.

These functions have global variables that require storage; uninitialized (zero initialized) global variables in the BSS segment and initialized global variables in the DATA segment.

This is why, you will always see BSS and DATA in all the binaries compiled with the libc. If you want to get rid of this, then you should write your own assembly program, like this (`asm.s`):

```
.globl _start
 _start:
    mov %eax, %ebx
```

And, then compile it without the libc:

```
$> gcc -nostdlib -o asm asm.s
```

You should reduce your footprint to the BSS and DATA segment on this ELF binary.

Comment: Thank you! I figured out my mistake, time to brush up my concepts of gcc and linking libraries.

Comment: No problem, this field is huge! You have to start somewhere! Good luck and keep going! :)

Comment: Please be more precise: "_These functions use a little bit of memory that is taken from the BSS and the DATA segment._" could better be told as "These functions have global variables that require storage; uninitialized (zero initialized) global variables in the BSS segment and initialized global variables in the DATA segment"

Answer (score 11):

`int main(){return 0;}` puts data in `.text` only.

```
$ echo 'int main(){return 0;}' | gcc -xc - -c -o main.o && size main.o
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
     67       0       0      67      43 main.o
```

You're probably `size`ing a fully linked executable.

```
$ gcc main.o -o main && size main
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1415     544       8    1967     7af main
```